# Modifying login MVC 5 Asp Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 5 and Asp Identity for a new app I am building. I need to modify the login process so only information pertaining to the users community is shown. I was thinking of creating another table with Community ID's and User ID's in it similar to the AspUserRoles table. How do I tie this into the login process? Sorry I am new to MVC coming from Web Forms :(

Thanks!

Comment: Apologies if I haven't understood correctly but are you after making your application multi-tenant? So every user belongs to a community?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a valid approach. So you'll end up with something like:

```
public class Community
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Members { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Community> Communities { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework will automatically generate a join table from that. Then, in your login, somehow, you feed the community id. That could be from a special URL, a hidden input, select box, whatever. It's up to you. Then, you just need to modify the sign in process slighly. By default in a generated project template, sign in is handled via the following line:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

You can see the code for `PasswordSignInAsync` [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/SignInManager.cs). But I'll post it here for posterity as well:

```
public virtual async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password,
    bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return SignInResult.Failed;
    }

    return await PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, isPersistent, shouldLockout);
}
```

So, just add your own version of this to `ApplicationSignInManager` in `IdentiyConfig.cs`:

```
public virtual async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(int communityId, string userName, string password,
    bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

    if (user == null || !user.Communities.Any(m => m.Id == communityId))
    {
        return SignInResult.Failed;
    }

    return await PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, isPersistent, shouldLockout);
}
```

Notice the extra condition. Then, you just need to modify the original call in the `Login` action to pass in the `communityId`:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(communityId, model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

Comment: Should I create another table that holds CommunityID and UserID's or just add CommunityId to the users table and pass it in when new users are created?

Comment: Again, once you add the two collection properties to each side of the relationship, Entity Framework will automatically create a join table for the M2M relationship.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the questions I am learning MVC on the fly and I still think in terms of web forms :(

Comment: One more question.. once they login I only want to show information based on the community ID site wide. How is this accomplished in MVC and EF? I am used to writing all this DAL and BI code myself so I am struggling a bit with EF :(